# Toad Automation load all various excel files from a folder

Tags: automation, toad, toad-scripting

I have to load all excel files into a table.

now the issue I am getting is that the file name is always going to be different no matter what and the same goes for the sheet. Is it possible to setup the toad automation to just load the all excel files using the first sheet regardless of its name as it will also be different. that way once it is done I want to move the excel files to a separate location.

Comment: Why tag this excel? Excel is not the issue you describe.

Comment: you do not see it in the first sentence ? they are excel files I have to load. and stack suggested I should use the excel tag.

Comment: But my point is you are using Toad ... not Excel - if you wanted to use Excel and VBA to do this then I would agree it should be tagged excel, but I say again it’s not an excel problem...

Comment: good point I have removed the tag excel from my question.